# cannot fetch data using Facebook app access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-access-token

I am trying to write a Facebook application. I can easily use permissions from a Facebook user. And I am trying to fetch some data from different Facebook tables using FQL. These are the permissions that my application has:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "installed": 1,
         "read_stream": 1,
         "status_update": 1,
         "photo_upload": 1,
         "video_upload": 1,
         "email": 1,
         "create_note": 1,
         "share_item": 1,
         "publish_stream": 1,
         "read_insights": 1,
         "manage_notifications": 1,
         "read_friendlists": 1,
         "publish_actions": 1,
         "user_birthday": 1,
         "user_religion_politics": 1,
         "user_relationships": 1,
         "user_relationship_details": 1,
         "user_hometown": 1,
         "user_location": 1,
         "user_likes": 1,
         "user_activities": 1,
         "user_interests": 1,
         "user_education_history": 1,
         "user_work_history": 1,
         "user_website": 1,
         "user_groups": 1,
         "user_events": 1,
         "user_photos": 1,
         "user_videos": 1,
         "user_photo_video_tags": 1,
         "user_notes": 1,
         "user_questions": 1,
         "user_about_me": 1,
         "user_status": 1,
         "user_games_activity": 1,
         "user_subscriptions": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

That means that I have permission to fetch data from stream table. Because it needs `read_stream` and `read_insight`. This is my url to fetch data:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT likes, comments, post_id, actor_id from stream where source_id=SOURCE_ID&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

but the result is 
`{
   "data": [
    ]
}`

completely empty. It gives no error.

However when I try it with my graph API access token with the same permissions, which uses user access token, I can easily fetch data.

Can't I fetch data from stream table using app's access token? Is there no way to fetch it using the app's access token?

My app's access token is not giving any error.
What is the problem with my access token?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch `stream` data using an app access token. You must authenticate a user to your app and use a user access token to get this data. If you change the application in the Graph API explorer, it authenticates you and still gains a user access token in your name.

Also, keep in mind that there is a setting under "Privacy Settings" where a user can inhibit all access to their data by apps. If this is set, you won't see anything for that particular user either in your app or the API explorer.

The empty data set is a normal result for Facebook when you don't have the permissions you need to view the data you've requested. If you dig into the API documentations, the Facebook API server first executes your query and then filters the results to show what is visible to your app and access token. That filter can remove all data so an empty data set gets returned.

Comment: But what if I want to access a post which is posted by my app while user is ofline. Do these rules still apply? I can not use user access_token because it will expire. I can not use offlie_access permission because it is not a long term solution. Do you have any advice?

Comment: You can request a long-term access token and store that locally. These are currently valid for 60 days. This can be used to make that request. You should have your app users visit and re-authorize your app frequently so that you can renew this token. I think the idea behind the deprecation of the offline_access permission is that if someone hasn't used your app in 60 days, they probably don't want to use it anymore.